# Return only numbers from a given string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this :

```
var s= -123456abcd@abc.com
```

I want to have this

```
var res=123456
```

How can I do that in javascript?
Should I use regular expression?
Can someone guide me to the right way please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var numbers = s.match(/\d/g);
```

#### Full example

```
var s= "-123456abcd@abc.com"
var numbers = s.match(/\d/g); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var resp = numbers.join(''); // "123456";
```

#### Short version

```
var resp = s.match(/\d/g).join('');
//or
var resp = s.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Comment: What if there's more than one number in his string? Then you're concatenating the numbers by using the `join` method. I wouldn't use `join`, I would just treat it like an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s= "-123456abcd@abc.com";
var matches = s.match(/\d+/g);
alert(matches.join(""));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/134/)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var s = "-123456abcd@abc.com";
var numbers = s.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZE22G/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match()` method to do this. It will return an array, which is good, because there may be more than one number hidden in your string.

```
var s = '-123456abcd@abc.com';
var numbers = s.match(/\d+/g);

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    alert(numbers[i]);
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QcJwz/

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything that is not a digit with nothing

```
var s = '-123456abcd@abc.com'
var s2 = s.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RUaB2/)

Comment: What if there's more than one number in his string? It's not clear what he wants to do in that case.

Comment: @ktm5124 - There is more than one number in the string, and it seems crystal clear to me, remove anything that is not a number!

Comment: I mean, what if this is the case? `var s = "abc123def456ghi7"`. In this case you might want to handle "123", "456", and "7" as distinct numbers.

Comment: no it can't be this case bcs all of my string are like the example i gave but this is a really good comment that i would like to know it's answer

Comment: @ktm5124 - You might, but that's not the question.